# Limit of function $f(x) = 2 (x = 1)$ for $x = 1$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Function $f$ has only $1$ at its domain, and $f(1) = 2$. Then, can we say that the limit for $x$ to $1$ exists?

According to the epsilon delta definition, the assumption is that $0 < |x - 1| < \delta$. But there is no such $x$ in $f$'s domain, since $1$ is the only element and it does not hold for $x = 1$.

It is known that every single proposition with its assumption being an empty set is true; and this leads to the conclusion that the epsilon delta proposition holds. Therefore, the limit exists.

However, the proposition still holds even if we change $|f(x)-2| < \epsilon$ to $|f(x)-3| < \epsilon$, so therefore the value of the limit can be any real(or even complex) number. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general: let $D$ be the domain of $f$, then the definition of $ \lim_{x \to x_0}f(x)$ requires that $x_0$ is an accumulation point of $D$. If $D=\{1\}$ and $x_0=1,$ then $x_o$ is not an accumulation point of $D$.

Comment: (+1) Right, I forgot the accumulation point requirement.

Comment: @gt6989b MSE said I needed to wait a few more minutes to accept it.

Comment: @Vue thanks for doing it -- sorry for asking explicitly, I just see a lot of answers upvoted by the OP without accepting...